# How to copy all user on from one linux server to another linux server?

Tags: linux, centos, users

I have one CentOS server with a lot of user there, let's say 500 users.
I want to migrate/copy all of these users to another CentOS server.
I only have root account on old server. How could i do that?

Comment: You should use ssh public/private key pairs and NOT passwords on any internet accessible server ... and only copy over those and disable ability to even login using passwords ... otherwise you're just asking to get hacked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to have the same users in the new system, you can get the list of users in your old server and add them in the new server with `useradd` within a loop as follows:

```
for i in $(cat users_list); do useradd $i; done
```

Note that this won't migrate the users data as you didn't mention it.

If you want to migrate the users with their old password and data, you can copy the lines concerning the users you want to migrate on files:

- /etc/passwd
- /etc/group
- /etc/shadow

From old server to new server.

Now you may also copy the /home directory structure to your new sytem, so that the users can have access to their data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since i don't know other user's password, how can i migrate them in order to use them in new server?

Comment: @TheOne Edited!